# How can I run Ubuntu inside a virtual machine on Windows 7?

Tags: boot, virtualization, architecture

When I tried to run Ubuntu in Windows Virtual PC I got this error:

> This kernel requires an x86-64 CPU, but only detected an i686 CPU.
>   Unable to boot – please use a kernel appropriate for your CPU

Later I learnt about enabling the virtualisation in the BIOS but I saw it is already enabled.

Why am I unable to run it?

Comment: What visualisation software are you using: VMWare, Virtualbox etc? Is your Windows7 32-bit or 64-bit and what guest OS are you trying to install?

Comment: @Warren Hill: tag says virtual-pc, so its about M$ virtualisation.

Answer (score 5):

You've downloaded a 64bit image and your processor can't handle 64bit (or, more likely your copy of Windows can't).

The fix is simple: download and use the 32bit version: go to the [Ubuntu Desktop download page](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) and select **32-bit** below **Choose your flavour**.

Answer (score 1):

The answer made by Sir Oli is right , but after googling a little there is more reason i got that -

```
This kernel requires an x86-64 CPU, but only detected an i686 CPU.
Unable to boot – please use a kernel appropriate for your CPU
```

is because of you are installing 64-bit operating system which is capable of Virtualization Technology on 32-bit hardware or if Intel VT-x or AMD-V is not enabled in the BIOS.

So for solving that check your BIOS and for Intel Processors  **ENABLE** the option **Intel Virtualization Technology** and for AMD Processors **ENABLE** - **AMD V** thats AMD Virtualization and remember your PC processor and motherboard should support this feature.

Comment: Sir Oli? Anyway, there are various help articles on this - e.g. http://www.sysprobs.com/disable-enable-virtualization-technology-bios

Comment: Oli the moderator here.. and yes the link u mentioned is relevant. That is all i was saying..

Comment: I know...... :D

Answer (score 0):

I am nowhere near being an expert in Ubuntu or Virtualization.  My Virtualization setting was enabled in the UEFI/BIOS and I sill wound up with this error.  So I switched from Windows Virtual PC to Oracle Virtual Box and I was able to easily create a virtual environment for UBUNTU.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @DavidFoerster This is an answer. If one piece of software can't handle the image but another can, that's an answer.